# regex for multiple formats decimals and thousand separator

Tags: regex, separator, decimal-point

I need regex to validate a number that could contain thousand seperators that would be one of three different characters (`.` `,` or ) or decimals that could be either `,` or `.`. There are no max or min values, so that isn't a concern. If a decimal isn't in the number, it should be added. Once detected, I would then be able to process the resulting expressions into a set standard format.

Example values that would need to be detected (values on the left are what will be detected, values on the right will be the output we will code to, but displayed here for the benefit of better a understanding of my needs):

`11,111.11` => `11111.11`

`11'111.11` => `11111.11`

`11 111.11` => `11111.11`

`11.111,11` => `11111.11`

`11'111,11` => `11111.11`

`11 111,11` => `11111.11`

`11,111` => `11111.00`

`11'111` => `11111.00`

`11 111` => `11111.00`

`11.111` => `11111.00`

This is needed for a web site where the input values could be different based on different standard formats (depending on the end-user). In Switzerland, all those potential combinations may be used.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which logic both `11.111` and `11,111` denotes `11111.00`? And how do you interpret `11,111,111,111` ?

Comment: Which language is this in? Javascript?

Comment: In Switzerland, the thousands separator could be a `.`, a `'`, a `,` or a space. They also use a `.` as the thousands separator, then they would use a `,` as the decimal point. However, I will be stripping all thousands separators and converting all decimals to a `.`.

Comment: I hope I never get in touch with an application that has implemented this logic. Especially if it is banking application. This is so dangerous.

Comment: @OnlineCop php on submit

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im `11,111,111,111` would be interpreted as `11111111111.00`

Comment: [This one will work](http://regex101.com/r/cZ7iN2/1) only for the first half. But as the other's have warned, this is a question is very ambiguous and needs to be clarified and still used with caution

Comment: How many passes are acceptable? For example, 1st pass could add any missing decimals: look for trailing `[,.]##` and if not found, append `.00`. 2nd pass would then replace all `[,.' ]` characters (that aren't part of the last `.##` digits).

Comment: As many passes as needed. There won't be too many potential errors I suspect, and the purpose is to validate the input. Later, in a separate process, that input will be added to a previous input `A+B` and the result will be displayed in a form...but this process will happen much later, and the value will only be used for display purposes. The displayed value will be in a non-thousand-separated decimal format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the snippet below since I don't see how to achieve this using a singe regular expression.

```
$string = array("0,89", "11,111,111,111", "11,111.11", "11'111.11", "11 111.11", "11.111,11", "11'111,11", "11 111,11", "11,111", "11'111", "11 111", "11.111");
$pattern = "/^(\d{1,3}([,\s.']\d{3})*|\d+)([.,]\d+)?$/";
foreach($string as $price){
    preg_match($pattern, $price, $matches);
    echo $matches[0] , " -> " , preg_replace("/[,\s.']/", "", $matches[1]) , ((!empty($matches[3])) ? preg_replace("/[,\s.']/", ".", $matches[3]) : ".00") , "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
0,89 -> 0.89
11,111,111,111 -> 11111111111.00
11,111.11 -> 11111.11
11'111.11 -> 11111.11
11 111.11 -> 11111.11
11.111,11 -> 11111.11
11'111,11 -> 11111.11
11 111,11 -> 11111.11
11,111 -> 11111.00
11'111 -> 11111.00
11 111 -> 11111.00
11.111 -> 11111.00
```

As you can see, in the first step, the pattern above will match any (valid) price format and place it into three groups. In the second step, the group (1) will be cleaned up of any separators while the separator in group (3) if exists, would be replaced with a dot (.) (and the zeros will be added if needed)

For more testings check the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rJ7yU4/2)

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification (not as an "answer" but because comments don't allow for the length of this response), are these the kinds of inputs you intend to encounter? Is it missing any scenarios?

**EDIT:** separated decimals, added a few 'invalid' cases.

```
### WITH DECIMALS ###

# No separators, with decimals (using '.')
1.00    10.00   100.00  1000.00 10000.00    100000.00   1000000.00  10000000.00 100000000.00

# No separators, with decimals (using ',')
1,00    10,00   100,00  1000,00 10000,00    100000,00   1000000,00  10000000,00 100000000,00

# Thousand separators (using ','), with decimals (using '.')
1,000.00    10,000.00   100,000.00  1,000,000.00    10,000,000.00   100,000,000.00

# Thousand separators (using '.'), with decimals (using ',')
1.000,00    10.000,00   100.000,00  1.000.000,00    10.000.000,00   100.000.000,00

# Thousand separators (using ' '), with decimals (using ',')
1 000,00    10 000,00   100 000,00  1 000 000,00    10 000 000,00   100 000 000,00

# Thousand separators (using "'"), with decimals (using '.')
1'000.00    10'000.00   100'000.00  1'000'000.00    10'000'000.00   100'000'000.00

# Thousand separators (using "'"), with decimals (using ',')
1'000,00    10'000,00   100'000,00  1'000'000,00    10'000'000,00   100'000'000,00


### WITHOUT DECIMALS ###

# No separators, no decimals
1   10  100 1000    10000   100000  1000000 10000000    100000000

# Thousand separators (using ','), no decimals
1,000   10,000  100,000 1,000,000   10,000,000  100,000,000

# Thousand separators (using '.'), no decimals
1.000   10.000  100.000 1.000.000   10.000.000  100.000.000

# Thousand separators (using ' '), no decimals
1 000   10 000  100 000 1 000 000   10 000 000  100 000 000

# Thousand separators (using "'"), no decimals
1'000   10'000  100'000 1'000'000   10'000'000  100'000'000


### INVALID, reusing separator and decimal indicator ###

1,000,00 10,000,00 100,000,00 1,000,000,00 10,000,000,00 100,000,000,00
1.000.00 10.000.00 100.000.00 1.000.000.00 10.000.000.00 100.000.000.00


### INVALID, non-numeric input or invalid separators ###

11a111.11
1-000 1-000.00 1-000,00 100!000.00
```

Comment: The second question is crucial. `Is it missing any scenarios?`

Comment: That is a well formatted clarification, and it does not have any missing scenarios.

Comment: And to clarify, this number will not be used for banking or even calculation but it's just for validations sake, as the client requested that we cater to the habits of different users. Also, if any pattern is missing it will not be that big of a deal as it will be rejected as invalid and the user will be asked to enter a new number. So, if we are missing any scenario we will find out during user testing.

Comment: For example, if `11a111.11` is input, we would automatically invalidate that. Alpha input, or input that is not `0-9`, `.`, `,`, `'` or space, would be invalid.

Comment: If you can break this into two steps, the first could add decimals to the end of each number: http://regex101.com/r/wH1yQ0/2. You may need to replace `,00` with `.00`. The second step would then remove all `[.,' ]` characters that are before those `[.,]\d\d`: http://regex101.com/r/wH1yQ0/4